# Getting updated data from realm

Tags: android, asynchronous, realm

What is the best practice to get data from realm that was put there asynchronously?

For example, I want to write some data to realm and access it when transactions completes. What is the correct way of doing it?

I encountered that if I write data to realm asynchronously I cannot access it from `onSuccess` callback unless I set `RealmChangeListener` on query, which adds some annoying boilerplate and also plainly unintuitive. Also I need to specify query that I want to listen to.

```
RealmList<RealmObject> contents = ...;
RealmResults<RealmWrappedContent> realmResults = realm.where(RealmWrappedContent.class)
                                        .equalTo("id", id)
                                        .findAllAsync();

OnSuccess notWorkingOnSuccess = () -> processResults(realmResults); // realmResults are empty

OnSuccess workingOnSuccess = () -> realmResults.addChangeListener(l -> {
    processResults(l);                                              // realmResults are valid and ready for access
    realmResults.removeChangeListeners();
});                                        

realm.executeTransactionAsync(bgRealm ->
            bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(contents), notWorkingOnSuccess, onError)  // if we try to access realmResults here, they will be empty

realm.executeTransactionAsync(bgRealm ->
            bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(contents), workingOnSuccess, onError)    // works fine
```

So, the question is:

**How do I access written to realm objects as soon as they are put in database (and not fall into callback hell)?**

We use RxJava heavily in our project. Maybe it can be used to help situation? Also I was thinking that if `executeTransactionAsync` could return `RealmResults` things would be much, much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately you got hit by this bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1893. We are just reviewing a fix for it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2780 and plan to make a release in the next few days. Once this is released, you should be able to properly access the data in `onSuccess`

Comment: @ChristianMelchior that would be wonderful to get implemented! Thanks. I'll catch up with the news (: